# Circular dependence cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I need to display an ListView between a LinearLayout and a Relative Layout. I want that the height of the ListView to be display according to the screen dimensions. For that, I put layout_height="wrap_content", and I user layout_above and layout_belowm but this returns this :"Circular dependence cannot exist in RelativeLayout". 
Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/roadmap_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    ........
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listvisit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/roadmap_linearlayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativelayout_listpostovisit"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/listview_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout_listpostovisit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listvisit"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

       .........

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the line `android:layout_below="@id/listvisit"` in the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want that the height of the ListView to be display according to the screen dimensions.

I am going to translate this as meaning "I want the `ListView` to fill the available screen space".

> For that, I put layout_height="wrap_content"

You cannot reliably use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on a `ListView`.

> and I user layout_above and layout_belowm but this returns this :"Circular dependence cannot exist in RelativeLayout"

That is because your outer `RelativeLayout` configuration has `relativelayout_listpostovisit` depend upon the position of `listvisit` and the position of `listvisit` depend upon the position of `relativelayout_listpostovisit`. That cannot work.

Either:

- Change `relativelayout_listpostovisit`, removing `android:layout_below="@id/listvisit"` and adding `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, or
- Switch the outer container to be a `LinearLayout` rather than a `RelativeLayout` and switch to using `android:layout_weight` to allocate extra space to the `ListView`.